# AllShortestPaths with more than one MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use the "allShortestPaths()" Method in a query with more than one MATCH.
Actually this query does look correct for me

```
MATCH (vs: VIRTUALSUITE {NAME: "Test VS Copy"})-[:INCLUDES_VERSION]->(productVersion: PRODUCT_VERSION)
WITH productVersion, vs
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((productVersion)-[:IS_BOMPARENT_OF*..]->(child: PRODUCT_VERSION))
RETURN vs, productVersion, child, p
```

but in fact I get a syntax error:

```
Unknown identifier `child`
Unknown identifier `vs`.
Unknown identifier `productVersion`.
Unknown identifier `child`.
Unknown identifier `p`.
```

Would be nice if someone could help me out! :)

Thanks and Greetings
Schakron

Comment: I would remove the space between the : and the label -> vs:VIRTUALSUITE

Comment: What version are you using? I've tried it in 2.1.2 (get syntax error) and 2.1.5 & 2.1.6 (both are working). So it might have been a bug in an older version

Comment: I just updated to 2.1.6. Now it works! Thanks for help :)